# UDP Socket Connection Refused on Receive

Tags: python, sockets

Using the following code in python, I have been able to send a message to the server, but I am unable to receive a response from the server. Here is the code:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.10.67.43"
UDP_PORT = 4000
message = b"hello\n"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
s.send(message)
s.recv(2048)
s.close()
```

And here is the error:

```
      8 s.connect((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
      9 s.send(message)
---> 10 s.recv(2048)
     11 s.close()
```

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I tried this script on two linux computers but with no luck on either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Weird stuff. At least, an error on s.recv is what it says in the error. I am assuming that maybe the server was either misconfigured or my computer isn't accepting connections from it.

Comment: There is no "connection" in UDP, so there is nothing to "accept". There is only sends and reads.  Any "connection" is a logical construct handled at the application layer, not a physical one handled at the transport layer, like in TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was connecting to the wrong host, and the computer that I was trying to connect to wasn't actually accepting any UDP traffic on that port. Thank you!

Comment: Makes sense.  In which case, the `send()` likely resulted in the network sending an ICMP error packet (either "host unreachable" or "port unreachble") back to your client machine, in which case the `recv()` would pick that up (due to the earlier `connect()`) and so it could report an error to your code.